# Semigroup and their monogenic semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

A subsemigroup $K$ of $S$ is said to be monogenic if $K = \langle a \rangle$ for some $a \in S$ and the order of $a$ is the size of $K$. If the order of $a$ is finite, then after some time power of $a$ will be repeated. Then the set $\{ x \in \mathbb N : (\exists y \in \mathbb N ) a^x  = a^y, x \neq y \}$ is non empty and so it has a least element says $m$ is called the index of $a$. The least element $r \in \mathbb N$ satisfy $a^{m+ r} = a^m$ is called the period of $a$. Every finnite monogenic subsemigroup can be represented by $M(m, r) = \langle a \rangle$.  I have found that the index of  $a^i \in \langle a \rangle$, where $i < m$ is  either $q$ or $q + 1$, where $ m = iq + r$ by divison algorithm theorem.

> > I want to find out what is the period of $a^i$, where $i < m$ ?

I would be thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: I know the index of $a^i$ but I am unable to find the period of $a^i$, where $i < m$.  Also,  I know the index and period of $a^i$ for $i \geq m$

Comment: Sorry, I misread.

Comment: I guess that the period of $a^i$ is the same as the order of $i$ in $\mathbf{Z}/r\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: @ YCor: What is the operation on $\mathbb Z/r\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @YCor: This is working. Thanks for your valuable comment